# Unable to logout of an application and return to the login page to re-enter auth credentials

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-active-directory, logout

When clicking on the Logout link which is an onClick event inside of an  tag a Refresh Token warning is displayed. When clicking on the refresh or back button in the browser I am taken to the same page in which I tried to logout from.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwYZP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHefk.png)

```
export default function Logout() {
  const ssoLogOut = process.env.VITE_SSO_LOGOUT_URL //https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout (VITE_SSO_LOGOUT)  const ssoLogIn = process.env.VITE_AUTH_URL // https://nonprod-emplogin.ise-nonprod.website.org (VITE_SSO_AUTH_URL)

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    localStorage.removeItem('cb_emp_login')
    ;(event.currentTarget.parentElement as HTMLFormElement).submit()
    window.location.href = (`${ssoLogIn}/logout?DURL=${window.location.origin}&post_logout_redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(window.location.origin)}`)
  }

  return (
    <form
      acceptCharset='utf-8'
      method='post'
      action={ssoLogOut}
      onClick={handleSubmit}
      className='logout'>
      <a href={ssoLogOut} onClick={handleSubmit} className = 'logout'>
        Logout
      </a>
    </form>
  )
}
```

(React.js) I've tried using the useHistory hook, using window.location.href, and using document.cookie to delete cookies. I was expecting to have the onClick event logout the user then direct them to the login page which is the base URL for Microsoft Azure Active Directory login serve. I do not have access to change the endpoint url in Microsoft AAD.

Expected after triggering the onClick event (logout):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32QLN.png)

Comment: You need to clear cookies before logging out. Microsoft oath saves cookies in browser if you clicked on "remember me".